# How to setup the definition file to use LINQ in an Azure Function?

Tags: c#, linq, azure-sql-database, azure-functions

I have created an Azure function that connects to an Azure SQL DB and executes direct SQL commands.  Now I would like to use LINQ instead.  I have used Visual Studios to create the definition file, but I am not sure how to reference the definition file once uploaded to the function.  The code below is getting the error:

> error CS1061: 'SqlConnection' does not contain a definition for 'Customers' and no extension method 'Customers' accepting a first argument of type 'SqlConnection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Here is the code I have for the Azure function:

```
using System.Net;
using Dapper;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# HTTP trigger function processed a request. RequestUri={req.RequestUri}");

    var cnnString  = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlConnection"].ConnectionString;
    var connection = new SqlConnection(cnnString);

    var result = from r in connection.Customers select r;

    foreach (var r in result)
    {
        log.Info(r.squid);
    }

    log.Info("Log added to database successfully!");

    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

Comment: I could be incorrect, but whenever `SqlConnection` object is used, it needs to correlate w/ `SqlCommand` (`SqlCommand` runs a query and uses the method `ExecuteReader` for select statements). In order to use `LINQ`, the tables need to be parsed into objects (like Entity Framework uses). The following link is `LINQ to SQL`, not `Entity Framework` (which I recommend) - https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/linq-to-sql-part-3-querying-our-database  -- Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Thank you for the comment Rob.   If a DataContext is needed, I am still not sure how to do that in an Azure Function.  The web site that you link to talks about the same method I am trying to use above, but not in an Azure Function.

Comment: Might want to take a look at this post as well. Note that you're not wrapping your `SqlConnection` object in a `using` statement`, nor are you opening the connection. (that's not relating to your error though -http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1110663/Azure-Functions-Tutorial-SQL-Database

Comment: Thank you for your comment Rob.  A 'using' statement is not necessary, and LINQ opens and closes the connection as needed.  The article referenced is for direct SQL calls, and does not address LINQ.  Still looking for a solution....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load in another class using #load. You can create new files using the `view files` Link at the bottom of the code window

**Run.csx File**

```
#r "System.Data.Linq"
#load "TodoItem.csx"

using System.Net;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;
using System.Configuration;

public static void Run(string input, TraceWriter log)
{        
    var cnnString  = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MS_TableConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    DataContext db = new DataContext(cnnString);     
    Table<todoItem> todoItems = db.GetTable<todoItem>();        
    IQueryable<todoItem> itemQuery = from todoItem in todoItems select todoItem;

    foreach (todoItem item in itemQuery)
    {
        log.Info($"ID={item.id}, Text={item.text}");
    }

    return;
}
```

**TodoItem.csx File**

```
#r "System.Data.Linq"
#r "System.Data"

using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;
using System.Data;

[Table(Name = "TodoItem")]
public class todoItem
{
    private string _id;
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey=true, Storage="_id")]
    public string id
    {
        get
        {
            return this._id;
        }
        set
        {
            this._id = value;
        }

    }

    private string _text;
    [Column(Storage="_text")]
    public string text
    {
        get
        {
            return this._text;
        }
        set
        {
            this._text=value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Naren for the answer and detailed example.